# document builder add html tags to doc

Tags: hibernate, xml-parsing

This is actually related to Hibernate when it tries to load the `persistence.xml` locally.

```
Here is the stacktrace and error
ERROR javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'HTML'.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
```

> Actually the persistence xml is plain (I minimized it from the larger one as it makes no difference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
</persistence>
```

> The issue is this line in the documentbuilder

```
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            docBuilder.setEntityResolver(resolver);
    doc = docBuilder.parse(source);

>The doc after parsed has HTML tags in it which it should not because its just a xml. I traveresed the nodes in the doc and got below elements

Found element HTML
Found element HEAD
Found element BODY
Found element PERSISTENCE
```

This is why XSD schema validation fails as it was not expecting html elements.

Anyone knows why and how to get over this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was having nekohtml-1.9.22.jar in the classpath. It is a parser and also a tag balancer. It was taken as the default parser and since it did not find HTML tags in the xml, it added it. Strange thing is it should not be the default for XML. Anyways removing it from classpath solved the issue.